# fit an `lm` model for every level of a factor

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to write a function that iterates (or uses `purrr::map()`) through every level of a factor, and fits an `lm()` model for the subset of the data where the factor is equal to that level.

To make a simple reproducable example with `mtcars`, just say that I'd like a different `lm` model for each value of `mtcars$gear`. I'll start by making it a factor, because my real problem involves iteration through a factor:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(factor_gear = factor(gear))
```

I'd like the function to fit every level of `factor_gear`. The levels are given by:

```
levels(mtcars$factor_gear)
```

i.e.

```
  [1] "3" "4" "5"
```

So the output I would be looking for would be:

```
fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars %>% filter(factor_gear=="3"))
fit2 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars %>% filter(factor_gear=="4"))
fit3 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars %>% filter(factor_gear=="5"))

fits <- list(fit1, fit2, fit3)
```

I've made a start on the function, but wasn't able to get it to work.

I thought that a function should:

1. get every level of of the factor into a vector
2. run an lm model for each level.

```
fit_each_level <- function(factor_variable) {

  # trying to: 1. get every level of of the factor into a vector
  factor_levels <- levels(df_cars$factor_variable)

  # trying to: 2. run an lm model for each level.
  for i in factor_levels {
    fit <- mtcars %>% filter(factor_variable==i [# every value of segment_levels]) %>% 
    lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = . )
  }

}

fit_each_level(factor_gear)
```

If the function worked well, I'd ultimately be able to do do it on another factor, eg:

```
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(factor_carb = factor(carb))

fit_each_level(factor_carb)
```

Comment: you can `group_by` the factor and run `lm` by group. Note that this can mess with your standard errors (running `mpg ~ cyl*factor_gear` may give different SEs than `mpg ~ cyl` by group)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `dplyr` 1.1.0 and above the newer syntax would be -

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  summarise(model = list(lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = pick(everything()))), 
           .by = factor_gear)
```

---

You can `nest` the dataframe and use `map` to apply `lm` for each `factor_gear`.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(factor_gear) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = .x)))

#  factor_gear data               model 
#  <fct>       <list>             <list>
#1 4           <tibble [12 × 11]> <lm>  
#2 3           <tibble [15 × 11]> <lm>  
#3 5           <tibble [5 × 11]>  <lm>
```

---

In the new `dplyr` you can use `cur_data` to refer to current data in group which avoids the need of `nest` and `map`.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(factor_gear) %>%
  summarise(model = list(lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = cur_data())))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is incredible, this will make my code so much easier. With your top solution, I have a question about `mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = .x)))`. When you first mention `data`, i.e. `= map(data`, it looks like the `data` hasn't been declared or assigned anywhere yet. How does that work? Does it come from the later `data = .x`?

Comment: That comes from `nest` actually. `nest` creates a list column with dataframes and the default column name is `data`. If you run only `mtcars %>% group_by(factor_gear) %>% tidyr::nest()` you'll see that.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, this link is a great way to learn more: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html

Comment: cur_data() has been deprecated, pick() is suggested instead

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the latest version of dplyr (1.0.0).  Then you can use:

```
model_coefs <- function(formula, data) {
  coefs <- lm(formula, data)$coefficients
  data.frame(coef = names(coefs), value = coefs)
}

mtcars %>%
  dplyr::mutate(factor_gear = factor(gear)) %>%
  dplyr::nest_by(factor_gear) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(model_coefs(mpg ~ cyl, data)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = coef, values_from = value)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   factor_gear [3]
  factor_gear `(Intercept)`   cyl
  <fct>               <dbl> <dbl>
1 3                    29.8 -1.83
2 4                    41.3 -3.59
3 5                    40.6 -3.2
```